# How to implement firebase cloud messaging in webapp?

Tags: web-applications, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

If anyone have any example app for implementation firebase cloud messaging in a webapp that would be highly helpful. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/chrome/client

Comment: I have looked through it. It states "The rest of this page describes the FCM support for Chrome apps and extensions only; for website support, see the push messaging codelab" and looking at the codelab example it only uses GCM in browser. Not FCM in server like a production app would require.

Comment: @jasan I don't think we have a runnable server side sample yet but please have a look at this doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Comment: Also in the codelab you pointed to, there is a section that explains how to send push notifications using an HTTP request which is basically what the server should do: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-07 but as the answer below mentions this is Chrome only at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase don't provide cloud messaging for web based applications. FCM or push notification can be implemented with specified chrome browser only. But still you can implement the firebase database to make your web application real time.
You can prefer this link [Firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start#initialize_the_database_web_sdk) and trigger the event on firebase database [Firebase Database Event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data#listen_for_events).
Hope this will help you. For complete implementation you can see this [Implementation Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38199481/5610686).