# Implementing Firebase Cloud Messaging on Web server

Tags: web, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a server running a website. I need this server to be able to administer (only downstream) notifications to three separate device groups, Android, iOS, and a client-side web app.

I am trying to use firebase cloud messaging.
With FCM, I plan on using the http protocol to send json messages.

Aside from this, I am pretty confused about where to go. I know that GCM tutorials should pretty much be exactly the same as FCM tutorials, but I am having trouble finding a tutorial to figure out what I need to be doing, as each tutorial seems to mix up the server and client side applications together, which is confusing me.

I have been through

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#choose

pretty thoroughly but it seems to gloss over some requisite knowledge that I don't have yet. Can anyone suggest a good starting place on how to implement FCM in the manner I am looking for? I am overall very new to web dev, less than 2 months, (using node, mongo, and scss) and feel a bit overwhelmed on how to get started on FCM.

I appreciate any feedback you guys can offer.

Comment: You seem to have a pretty good grasp of the basics. Unfortunately recommending off-site resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow. That said, this answer shows [how to send messages using a node.js script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38016996/209103)

Comment: That's a pretty good link, that looks like what I'm looking for. Man, I've been on this community long enough to know better. Thanks for the feedback! Is there anothee section of this site or another community that's more suited for that type of question?

Comment: I'd be interested in specifically what you think was glossed over in the documentation. Could you give some examples?

Comment: hello, I have done this with using PHP at server side. If it will be helpful to you I can share?

Comment: @ArthurThompson , once I figure out what I am doing, I will let you know what I was missing.

Comment: @devqualwebs that would be great! I am using js, but any examples help!

Answer (score 8):

as you have written that you are planning to get notifications on all three platforms that are android, iOS, and a client-side web app.
You can use firebase to get real time notification or desired data that's good but you have to keep this in your mind that each one has a little different process to achieve this compared to each other.
Very first you have to choose any of one and start the implementation.
Let's start from the begin...

A common process for using firebase into your application to create a project at https://console.firebase.google.com/ .

After creating project you will be able to see the firebase key that will be used in your application. You can see this at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/project-[your_project_number]/overview.

I hope you have done this already but don't forget to give permission to Database and Storage at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/project-[your_project_number]/database/rules and https://console.firebase.google.com/project/project-[your_project_number]/storage/rules.

For database just leave this...

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

For storage just leave this...

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/project-[your_project_number].appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

It will define that you can use it publicly no need to of any verifaction at firebase end. If you want to add any kind of verification you can go through https://console.firebase.google.com/project/project-[your_project_number]/authentication/providers .

Now start with the SERVER to WEB APPLICATION notification. First of all I want to let you know FCM (firebase cloud messaging) can be implemented with Android, iOS and web(specified Google Chrome) only. So for using it on all browser we have to implement the firebase database.
At js side. You have to put something like, what you have seen in Overview.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "your_api_key",
    authDomain: "project-[your_project_number].firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://project-[your_project_number].firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "project-[your_project_number].appspot.com",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

On server side for triggering an event or notification you can use CURL. As you have mentioned that you are using Node.js so this https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app can help you. 
I have achieved it by applying CURL at server side on PHP with CodeIgniter. I am attaching the code below. You can see the CURL example here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-put

```
<?php 
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

//PHP CURL FOR NOTIFICATION
function booking_notification($notif_arr, $notif_type)
{
    //GET CI 
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $url = 'put_your_firebase_database_url_here';
    $key = 'put_firebase_key';
    $notif_arr = {'Key':'values'};//THIS IS THE DATA WHAT YOU WILL NEED TO SHOW ON FRONT END TO NOTIFY
    $notif_type = 'notification'; //THIS IS THE NAME JSON WHICH WILL BE CREATED IF NOT EXIST AT FIREBASE DATABASE
    $headers = array(
       'Authorization: key=' . $key,
       'Content-Type: application/json'
   );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url."/".$notif_type.".json");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

   // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($notif_arr));

   // Execute post
   $result = curl_exec($ch);

   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
       // Close connection
       curl_close($ch);

       return FALSE;
   }
   else
   {
       // Close connection
       curl_close($ch);
       return TRUE;
   }
}
```

Now let's see how we can get the notification when it will be fired from server side.

JAVASCRIPT

```
var fireBaseJSONref = firebase.database().ref().child("notification"); //BY THIS YOU CAN GET THE JSON OF FIREBASE DATABASE
fireBaseJSONref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        if (!ignoreItems) {
            console.log(snapshot.val());//THIS WILL PRINT THE DATA WHAT YOU HAVE TRIGGERD FROM SERVER
        }
});
/* WHEN FIRST TIME ANY DATA SENT TO DATABASE OF FIREBASE AFTER PAGE LOAD */


fireBaseJSONref.once('value', function(snapshot) {ignoreItems = false}); //THIS WILL HELP YOU TO NOT TO CALL FOR PREVIOUSLY ADDED ITEM IN FIREBASE DATABASE. WHEN NEW DATA WILL BE ONLY THEN IT WILL CALL.
```

This will help you and figure out where you were confusing. Let me know if this will work for you, I will improve it for android and iOS also.

Comment: wow, what a wonderful explanation. I am going to comb through this very carefully and let you know how it goes.

Comment: So in your PHP code, you are  using a php function consisting of mostly curl requests, which makes sense to me. I am not sure is how the php code results in a notification. 

From what I see, to send a GCM notification using cURL, you need to include something like  https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

Is the example you included just an example of some cURL stuff ( not neccesarily notifications), or am I missing something fundamental? I also do not see how the php chooses which user gets the notification, unless it is in the key value pair...seriously, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Yeah you are right, once again I wanna get your attention that it is not FCM. It is firebase database implementation for getting real time data on web base applications. It is up to you how you want to perform action on that. It doesn't work like push notification. I have created a chat app as well as real time notification by implementing it. I will include the android push notification process as I will get some time.

Comment: that's good to see. It means you are able to get real time data over the browsers and I hope you have started playing with push notifications on mobile too.

Comment: hello. can we get the complete demo for the fcm push notofication with codeigniter?

Comment: Hi @PritishJoshi - am trying to implement web push via FCM, but since it does not work for IE, am trying to see if I can ue this firebase database implementation for the same. Can you pls let me know if you tried this in IE and it works? Also do you have a Java implementation of the php code you shared, for updating database from the backend server? I'm planning to create the firebase database on IE clients (since FCM works on chrome/firefox), and update the database from backend code. So it will trigger the change on the firebase database, through which I can just trigger a notification.