# Data is not saving using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using following code to save data on firebase . But it is giving permission denied error.Here is my code. I have followed all instruction given by firebase.

```
 buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);
                String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
                String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();
                Person person = new Person();
                person.setName(name);
                person.setAddress(address);
                ref.child("Person").setValue(person);
                ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);
                            String string = "Name: " + person.getName() + "\nAddress: " + person.getAddress() + "\n\n";
                            textViewPersons.setText(string);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                        Log.e("The read failed: ", firebaseError.getMessage());
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606853/firebase-permission-denied-when-reading-data-after-authentication

Comment: check your permissions on firebase console, under database -> rules

Comment: I am getting following in rule part.
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}

Comment: sanjay you should have a look of this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/38199481/5610686](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38199481/5610686)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have following rule in your Rules Tab:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

This rule means only authenticated users would be able to perform read and write operations.

Just change it to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

**Caution:** This rule means that anyone can read and write to your firebase database.

**Steps:** Go to Firebase Console -> Select Project -> Select Database from left handside menu -> Click on Rules tab -> Copy the rules over there.

Comment: How can I set it up so I don't have to register the user but only the App can access the Database?

Comment: @Si8 check my updated answer.

Comment: ThNk you. But no way to prevent anyone else accessing it than right?

Comment: @ChintanSoni I have the set the same rules, but still my data does not get reflected in the firebase console.